# How do you eliminate progress dialog on response of retrofit if it gets "[]"

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

As the title says `How do you eliminate progress dialog on response of retrofit if it gets "[]"`

My response.body().getAsJsonArray() gets []. I want when it gets [] my progressdialog will dismiss.

I've tried

> response.body().getAsJsonArray().toString() == "[]";
>   response.body().getAsJsonArray().toString() == null;
>   response.body().getAsJsonArray().equals("[]");

```
public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                if (response.body().getAsJsonArray() == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Data to display.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                } else if (response.body().getAsJsonArray().equals("[]")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Data to display.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                } else {
                        // Showing progress dialog
                        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                        pDialog.setMessage("Plotting.... Please wait.");
                        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        pDialog.show();

                        System.out.println(response.body().getAsJsonArray() + " JsonArray");

                        final PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getAsJsonArray().size(); i++) {

                            JsonElement location_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                            JsonObject location_obj = location_array.getAsJsonObject();
                            String loc = location_obj.get("location").toString();
                            String locString = loc;
                            locString = locString.replace("\"", "");
                            String location = String.valueOf(locString);

                            JsonElement lat_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                            JsonObject lat_obj = lat_array.getAsJsonObject();
                            String lati = lat_obj.get("lat").toString();
                            String latiString = lati;
                            latiString = latiString.replace("\"", "");
                            String lat = String.valueOf(latiString);

                            JsonElement lng_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                            JsonObject lng_obj = lng_array.getAsJsonObject();
                            String longi = lng_obj.get("lng").toString();
                            String longiString = longi;
                            longiString = longiString.replace("\"", "");
                            String lng = String.valueOf(longiString);

                            polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);
                            polylineOptions.width(3);

                            if (lat == null || lat.equals("null") || (lng == null && lng.equals("null") || (lat == "" || (lng == "") ||
                                    (lat.isEmpty()) || (lng.isEmpty())))) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Snail trail has no value.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        mMapSnailTrail.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                    }
            }
```

Comment: You can check array size <= 0

Comment: Hi CLIFFORD, I've tried it and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check **SIZE**

```
else if (response.body().getAsJsonArray().size()==0) 
               {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Data to display.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
```